# Create a listof in kotlin from a String

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a string like the following:

```
val myString = ("jan, apr, may, aug, sep, dec")
```

My intention is to create a list from that string, something like this:

```
val myList = listof (myString)
```

The result is a single item with all the elements of the String.

I have tried several ways to do it, I am looking for a way to convert a String to List but without success.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html (e.g. `val myList = myString.split(", ")`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bezkoder.com/kotlin-convert-string-list/

```
val input: String = "One, Two, Three, Four, Five"

//inside the split(character) you indicate the character that separates each value
var result: List = input.split(",").map { it.trim() }
```